# XML format in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-attribute

I am looking for an XML output like this:

```
<EmployeeCounts>
  <Count DESIGNATION="CLERK">200</Count>
  <Count DESIGNATION="MANAGER">1</Count>
  <Count DESIGNATION="PROFESSOR">4</Count>
</EmployeeCounts>
```

I am struggling to get the same format as mentioned above.

I used this query but it is erroring out

```
   SELECT  XMLELEMENT ("EmployeeCounts"
   ,XMLELEMENT("COUNT",
   XMLATTRIBUTES (e.DESIGNATION as "DESIGNATION", count(*))
                  )
   ) AS "emp"
   FROM employees e
   GROUP BY e.DESIGNATION ;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ORA-19208: parameter 2 of function XMLELEMENT must be aliased 19208.
00000 - "parameter %s of function %s must be aliased"
*Cause: The indicated parameter of the XML generation function has not 
been aliased, although it is an expression. *Action: Specify an alias 
for the expression using the AS clause. 
Error at Line: 6 Column: 14
```

But I don't want an alias for the count as per the format mentioned above.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Please add that to the question

Comment: Added the errors to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dijkgraaf's solution will resolve the error, but will not output the desired XML format.  Try the following which removes the COUNT from the XMLATTRIBUTES function, and utilizes XMLAGG so you get one set of EmployeeCounts tags:

```
SELECT
    XMLELEMENT("EmployeeCounts"
        , XMLAGG(
            XMLELEMENT("Count"
                , XMLATTRIBUTES(e.designation AS "DESIGNATION")
                , COUNT(1)
            )
        )
    )
FROM
    employees e
GROUP BY
    e.designation;
```

Comment: What does the output of that look like?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf [Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9dbd37/1) a SQLFiddle comparing the two.

Comment: Glad to know, @Tina!  If this was useful to you, please consider marking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a choice about not aliasing it.

```
SELECT  XMLELEMENT ("EmployeeCounts"
,XMLELEMENT("COUNT",
XMLATTRIBUTES (e.DESIGNATION as "DESIGNATION", count(*) as DESCOUNT)
              )
) AS "emp"
FROM employees e
GROUP BY e.DESIGNATION ;
```

You could try the following, but aliasing things to reserved words can be problematic sometimes.

```
SELECT  XMLELEMENT ("EmployeeCounts"
,XMLELEMENT("COUNT",
XMLATTRIBUTES (e.DESIGNATION as "DESIGNATION", count(*) as Count)
               )
) AS "emp"
```

FROM employees e
   GROUP BY e.DESIGNATION ;